# PHP - No Session, No Post - What Else?

Tags: php, session, post, server

I am making a small two page php project for someone.
I have a login page which redirects to a page with 20-odd checkboxes populated from the DB.

On login if the details are valid it creates a session user and a few others.
Locally everything is fine.

On the server however, it's not configured to use any custom session path and apparently is a shared hosting eviroment so I can't change the php.ini to include the session info.

It seems that the host is also blocking php post information.

Is there any other way I can simulate the same effect as having a session variable?

Comment: What should be the "same effect"? If sessions are not working, you should ask your hosting provider for help

Comment: Hi Nico Thanks for the reply.
They say that they can't make changes to the php.ini (for session path) and obviously wouldn't create custom session variables in the default path. This is because it is a shared environment of some sort.

Comment: Normal hosting environment does not require you to mess with session path at all to support session. They also do not block POST request at all. If that were the case, you'd best change to another hosting vendor.